# Как передать информацию о нажатии кнопки наушников?

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня есть проводной наушник с микрофоном. Кроме наушников на гарнитуре есть одна единственная кнопка. Я пишу приложение на Android Studio.

Как можно передать информацию приложению, что эта кнопка нажата или не нажата?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В активити переопределите метод `onKeyDown` и обработайте кейкод [`KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK):

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```